# Get Results From Snap To Road API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

Need some help.
So i'm using Google API Snap To Road.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$jsonarr = array();
$today=date("Y-m-d");

$ACCOUNT=$_GET['ACCOUNT'];
$ticket_no=$_GET['ticket_no'];
require_once("config/msdb_connect.php");

$query = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM TblGps WHERE DOOR = '".$ticket_no."' AND     DATETIME BETWEEN '".$today." 00:00:00' AND '".$today." 23:59:59' ORDER BY DATETIME DESC");
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query))
{
  //parameters
  $lng=$row['LONG'];
  $lat=$row['LAT'];
  //$data = array('lat'=>$lat,'lng'=>$lng);
  //echo $latlng = GetArray($data);

$jsonarr[] = array(
                        'id' => $row['ID'],
                      'account' => $row['ACCOUNT'],
                      'datetime' =>date("m/d/Y     H:i:s",strtotime($row['DATETIME'])),
                      'loc' => $row['LOCATION'],
                      // 'speed' => $row['SPEED'],
                      'longi' => $lng,
                      'lat' => $lat,
                      'lac' => $row['LAC'],
                      'cid' => $row['CID'],
                      // 'engine' => $row['ENGINE'],
                      'remarks' => $row['REMARKS']
                      );
}

$path = GetArray($jsonarr);
$snailtrail=GetSnailTrail($path);

function GetArray($array){

  $stringdata = "";
  for($i = 0 ; $i <= count($array) - 1 ; $i++){
    $rows = (object)$array[$i];
    if($i == count($array) - 1) $stringdata .= $rows->lat.','.$rows->longi;
    else $stringdata .= $rows->lat.','.$rows->longi.'|';
  }
  return $stringdata;
 }
function GetSnailTrail($path){
    $key='AIzaSyDRlfacNyHn7ZOsC0FzufqZ_rtQYfZD6wA';
    $url='https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path='.$path.'&interpolate=true&key='.$key.' ';

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

     $api_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $result = json_decode($api_response);

    $result = (object)$result;
    $result = (object)$result->location;

    return $result;
  }
```

So I'm fetching longtitude and latitude from my databse.
Then, i'll be using my function GetArray to compose it as multiple records for the paerameter path in GetSnailTrail function.

So it will be like this before sending on API:

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=14.567467,121.030726|14.566950,121.030497|14.567447,121.031204|14.566947,121.030520|14.566947,121.030520|14.567590,121.031181|14.567590,121.031181|14.567377,121.031236|14.566947,121.030520|14.567447,121.031204|14.566947,121.030520|14.566947,121.030520|14.566947,121.030520|14.566947,121.030520|14.567590,121.031181|14.567377,121.031236|14.567447,121.031204|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567590,121.031181|14.567377,121.031236|14.567590,121.031181|14.567377,121.031236|14.567447,121.031204|14.567377,121.031236|14.567447,121.031204|14.567377,121.031236|14.567466,121.030726|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567447,121.031204|14.567377,121.031236|14.567056,121.030569|14.567012,121.030539|14.567049,121.030568|14.567009,121.030545|14.567468,121.030728|14.567031,121.030549|14.567007,121.030545|14.567098,121.030403|14.567037,121.030548|14.567178,121.030624|14.566899,121.030486|14.566946,121.030520|14.567056,121.030569|14.567056,121.030569|14.567056,121.030569|14.566946,121.030520|14.566947,121.030522|14.566947,121.030522|14.566947,121.030522|14.567103,121.030594|14.566946,121.030520|14.566947,121.030522|14.566947,121.030524|14.567028,121.030556|14.566780,121.030502|14.566780,121.030502|14.567103,121.030594|14.567103,121.030594|14.566947,121.030522|14.566946,121.030520|14.566946,121.030520|14.566946,121.030520|14.566947,121.030524|14.566947,121.030524&interpolate=true&key=AIzaSyDRlfacNyHn7ZOsC0FzufqZ_rtQYfZD6wA
```

After that the API will return a result like this:

```
{
  "snappedPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 14.567361300000002,
        "longitude": 121.03068420000001
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJF6oagKzJlzMRlFWOLr4F1SI"
}
```

For some reason I can't echo or get the response to input it on my `$jsonarr`.
What to do after getting the response?
Thank you

Comment: Did curl provide any error ? Refer: [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php). and `var_dump($api_response)`.

Comment: Yes it displays 411 Error

Answer (score 1):

Given the url and associated data it returns in the browser to access each part of the returned data I found this worked ok, assuming that `$data` is assigned the response from the curl request.

The curl request was done using GET rather than POST and the response decoded outside of the function. Previously your code was trying to access `$result->location` ~ whereas it should be `$result->snappedPoints`

```
    function GetSnailTrail( $path=false ){
        if( !$path )return false;
        $key='AIzaSyDRlfacNyHn7ZOsC0FzufqZ_rtQYfZD6wA';
        $url='https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path='.$path.'&interpolate=true&key='.$key.' ';

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        return $result;
    }

    $path='14.567467,121.030726|14.566950,121.030497|14.567447,121.031204|14.566947,121.030520|14.566947,121.030520|14.567590,121.031181|14.567590,121.031181|14.567377,121.031236|14.566947,121.030520|14.567447,121.031204|14.566947,121.030520|14.566947,121.030520|14.566947,121.030520|14.566947,121.030520|14.567590,121.031181|14.567377,121.031236|14.567447,121.031204|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567590,121.031181|14.567377,121.031236|14.567590,121.031181|14.567377,121.031236|14.567447,121.031204|14.567377,121.031236|14.567447,121.031204|14.567377,121.031236|14.567466,121.030726|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567377,121.031236|14.567447,121.031204|14.567377,121.031236|14.567056,121.030569|14.567012,121.030539|14.567049,121.030568|14.567009,121.030545|14.567468,121.030728|14.567031,121.030549|14.567007,121.030545|14.567098,121.030403|14.567037,121.030548|14.567178,121.030624|14.566899,121.030486|14.566946,121.030520|14.567056,121.030569|14.567056,121.030569|14.567056,121.030569|14.566946,121.030520|14.566947,121.030522|14.566947,121.030522|14.566947,121.030522|14.567103,121.030594|14.566946,121.030520|14.566947,121.030522|14.566947,121.030524|14.567028,121.030556|14.566780,121.030502|14.566780,121.030502|14.567103,121.030594|14.567103,121.030594|14.566947,121.030522|14.566946,121.030520|14.566946,121.030520|14.566946,121.030520|14.566947,121.030524|14.566947,121.030524';

    $data=GetSnailTrail( $path );

    if( $data ) {

        $json=json_decode( $data,true );
        $points=$json['snappedPoints'];

        foreach( $points as $key => $value ){
            $obj=(object)$value;
            $lat=$obj->location['latitude'];
            $lng=$obj->location['longitude'];
            $index=property_exists($obj,'originalIndex') ? $obj->originalIndex : 'n/a';
            $id=$obj->placeId;
            echo 'id:'.$id.' index:'.$index.' lat:'.$lat.' lng:'.$lng.'<br />';
        }
    }
```

You could simplify the code further when constructing the path initially. Rather than a complicated function to process the `$jsonarr` data if you were to construct an array and populate with lat/lng in the `while` loop like this:

```
$pathdata=array();

while( $row = mssql_fetch_array( $query ) ){
    $jsonarr[] = array(
        'id'        =>  $row['ID'],
        'account'   =>  $row['ACCOUNT'],
        'datetime'  =>  date( "m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime( $row['DATETIME'] ) ),
        'loc'       =>  $row['LOCATION'],
        'longi'     =>  $row['LONG'],
        'lat'       =>  $row['LAT'],
        'lac'       =>  $row['LAC'],
        'cid'       =>  $row['CID'],
        'remarks'   =>  $row['REMARKS']
    );
    $pathdata[]="{$row['LAT']},{$row['LONG']}";
}

$path=implode('|',$pathdata);
```

Then you can `implode` the data using the chosen delimiter ( `|` ) to achieve the string of points.

To process this with javascript you could play about with the following:

```
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* \$data is already a json object, echo it in javascript and process */
    var path={$data};

    function processpath( path ){
        var json=path.snappedPoints;
        for( var o in json ){
            try{
                var point=json[ o ];
                if( typeof( point )!='undefined' ){

                    var lat=point.hasOwnProperty('location') && point.location.hasOwnProperty('latitude') ? point.location.latitude : false;
                    var lng=point.hasOwnProperty('location') && point.location.hasOwnProperty('longitude') ? point.location.longitude : false;
                    var index=point.hasOwnProperty('originalIndex') ? point.originalIndex : 'n/a';
                    var id=point.hasOwnProperty('placeId') ? point.placeId : 'n/a';

                    if( lat && lng ) console.log( 'id:%s, index:%s, lat:%s, lng:%s', id, index, lat, lng );
                }
            }catch( err ){
                console.warn( err );
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    processpath( path );
</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May i ask how to get rid of 'BR'?

Comment: oh, sorry - `BR` is a locally defined constant - I always forget to remove that when posting answers... it is `<br />`

Comment: Thank you...But how can i put that on the $jsonarray which will be get by my javascript to display?and not the long lat from database?

Comment: There was no mention of javascript. You could process the entire response in javascript by echoing the response as a javascript variable and not process in php. Can you clarify what you mean and where you would be using the javascript?